# Create SharePoint Site Using REST API and Powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, rest

I'm trying to create a SharePoint site using the REST API with Powershell.  I've successfully created lists, modified lists, and many other things but creating a site has me stumped.  Below is the code that builds the request that I invoke.  Authentication works so I have removed those sections of code.  When I run the script I get a 400 Bad Request so I'm thinking that I'm not including something in the headers or in the body.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$webURL = "https:// <SharePoint site URL> "
$urlAuth = $webUrl + "/_api/web/webinfos/add"

<Section Removed - Get FedAuth Token>

<Section Removed - Get FormDigest Value>

params = @{} 
params.Headers = @{"Accept" = "application/json; odata=verbose"; "X-RequestDigest" = $formDigest; "Content-Type" = "application/json;odata=verbose"} params.Uri = $urlAuth 
params.Body = [pscustomobject]@{
       _metadata = @{type = "SP.WebCreationInformation"}
       Url = "testsubsite"
       Title = "testsubsite"
       Description = "siteDescription"
       Language = "1033"
       WebTemplate = "STS"
       UseUniquePermissions = "False"
       } | ConvertTo-Json 
$params.Method = "POST" 
$params.WebSession = $session

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: @Nullldata - Sharepoint 2013

Comment: I've added tags to your question to indicate SharePoint 2013. It helps! :)

Comment: Just out of interest, does it have to be using REST? There are other ways to create SharePoint sites in PowerShell: New-SPSite and New-SPWeb are 2 cmdlets that can help with this...

Comment: @Nullldata - I have use certificate based authentication to do anything on SharePoint.  I was under the assumption that I couldn't use the cmdlets with certificate based authentication.  Is this a correct assumption?   Cmdlets would make this so much easier.

Comment: Might be worth trying to see.... Can you access the SP Server's PowerShell?

If so, try something like: New-SPWeb "https://somesite/subweb1" -Template "STS#0" 

Remember to edit the URL in the command.

You could also try remote powershell... https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

Comment: @Nullldata - Access to the server would make my life so much easier.   I work in highly secured environment and can't even do a remote Powershell session to the server.

Comment: Unlucky. It doesn't sound like you have an easy set up there. Can you get Central Admin access in the browser?